# Expectation of a distribution involving exponential

Tags: integration, statistics

$  f(y) =
\begin{cases}
e^y,  & \text{if $y<0$} \\
0, & \text{if elsewhere }
\end{cases}$

Find $E[e^{\frac{3Y}{2}}]$.

I wrote the integration

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{\frac{5y}{2}} dy$

Then how do I proceed. Kind request: Please give an elaborated answer because I am asked the moment generating function in the next part.

Comment: Your $f(y)$ cannot be the PDF of a random variable, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)\,dy\neq 1$.

Comment: Note that $E(Y)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} yf(y) dy$

Comment: I corrected the question. There  was a typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for a measurable function $g$, and a random variable $Y$ with density $f_Y$ we have $$\mathbb E[g(Y)] = \int_{\mathbb R}g(y)f_Y(y)\,\mathsf dy, $$ provided that $\mathbb E[|g(Y)|]<\infty$. In this case, $f_Y(y) = e^y\cdot\mathsf 1_{(-\infty,0)}(y)$ and $g(y) = e^{ty}$, where $t\in\mathbb R$. We compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left [e^{tY}\right] &= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{ty}e^y\cdot\mathsf 1_{(-\infty,0)}(y)\,\mathsf dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{y(1+t)}\,\mathsf dy\\
&= \frac1{1+t}, \quad t>-1.
\end{align}
When $t=\frac32$, we have
$$\mathbb E\left[e^{\frac32Y} \right] = \frac1{1+\frac32} = \frac25. $$